# Magento2. Use non AMD javascript scripts

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs

I am trying to load an external javascript in my Magento 2.1.x installation in this way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _iub = _iub || [];
        _iub.csConfiguration = {
            siteId: xxx,
            consentOnScrollDelay : 1500,
            callback: {
                onConsentGiven: function(){
                    dataLayer.push({'event': 'iubenda_consent_given'});
                }
            },
            cookiePolicyId: xxx,
            lang: "it",
            banner: {
                fontSize: "13", applyStyles: false,
                html:"Privacy policy HTML"
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js" charset="UTF-8" async></script>
```

Including the script `//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js` breaks all the other javascript requirejs functionalities.

I tried to include the script in the requirejs way, editing my theme requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    "map" : {
        "*" : {
            ...
            'iubenda' : '//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js'
        }
    }
};
```

and changing its inclusion in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _iub = _iub || [];
        _iub.csConfiguration = {
            siteId: xxx,
            consentOnScrollDelay : 1500,
            callback: {
                onConsentGiven: function(){
                    dataLayer.push({'event': 'iubenda_consent_given'});
                }
            },
            cookiePolicyId: xxx,
            lang: "it",
            banner: {
                fontSize: "13", applyStyles: false,
                html:"Privacy policy HTML"
            }
        };
    </script>

    <script>
        require(['iubenda'], function(){});
    </script>
```

But this does not solve the errors.

The common error thrown is

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){return l}
```

How can I add external non AMD scripts to my Magento 2.1.x without breaking the requirejs functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

You must create the javascript as follows:

```
<script>
    var _iub = _iub || [];
    _iub.csConfiguration = {
        siteId: xxx,
        consentOnScrollDelay: 1500,
        callback: {
            onConsentGiven: function () {
                dataLayer.push({'event': 'iubenda_consent_given'});
            }
        },
        cookiePolicyId: xxx,
        lang: "it",
        banner: {
            fontSize: "13", applyStyles: false,
            html: "Privacy policy HTML"
        }
    };
    $.getScript("//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js");
</script>
```

You must remove `...` requirejs-config.js

Old:

```
var config = {
    "map" : {
        "*" : {
            ...
            'iubenda' : '//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js'
        }
    }
};
```

New:

```
var config = {
    "map" : {
        "*" : {
            'iubenda' : '//cdn.iubenda.com/cookie_solution/safemode/iubenda_cs.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Doing this won't solve my problem. Requiring 'iubenda' script causes the breaking of other scripts. In additon, the code you include after having required iubenda must be before the require.

Comment: I updated my answer, Try.

Comment: Sorry, but this also does not solve my problems. The JS errors are still there

Comment: Please fill in your question with the error you receive.

Comment: see my edited answer